# Design a sine function with the given properties : it has a period of 12 hr with a minimum value of -4 at t = 0 and a maximum value of 4 at t = 6hr.

Tags: calculus

**What I understand so far :**

Intuitively this question gives me a yuuuuuge hint, it tells me at t=0, t = -4. So that let's me know that I have a phase shift of -4 immediately.

I understand what a period is, I understand what a phase shift is, I understand what amplitude and vertical displacement are and how they work.

I'm just not sure how to build a function even with that info at my disposal.

***My ultimate question here isn't to find an answer, but to be given a hint or a pointing in the right direction. Is there anything that you, my acquaintances at stackexchange have to offer?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether graphing the function from an equation, or finding the equation from the graph, or from the key data, make sure you know all this information.

Max
Min
Midline
Amplitude
Period
Frequency

Phase shift

We know the max and the min.  The mid is the average between the two.
Midline: $y=0$
Amplitude is the distance from the midline to the max or half the difference between the max and the min.
Amplitude: $4$
Period$\times$Frequency $= 2\pi$
Frequency: $\frac {\pi}{6}$

Phase shift... The minimum of sine function is at $\frac {3\pi}{2}$

$y = 4\sin\left(\frac {\pi}{6}t - \frac {3\pi}{2}\right) + 0$

The zero is superfluous, but that is where the adjustment for the midline would be.

You could also set this up as a cosine function.  Cosine is nice, because the maximum aligns with 0, often eliminating the need for phase shift.

$y = -4\cos\left(\frac {\pi}{6}t\right)$

Comment: Doug, you're just on another level that I'm really excited to grow into one day.

Comment: @doug_M so about the frequency. . . What is that exactly?

Comment: The frequency is the inverse of the period.  It is how many cycles of waves do you get in an interval of $2\pi$.  It is also the coefficient of $t$ or $x$ inside the sine function.

Comment: @doug_M doug, I took a small break and I looked over my textbook. The word "frequency" does not appear. So, I checked the index. Doesn't appear there either. So, what I'm assuming is that this book assumes that I have background knowledge in trig or was written by an incompetent author. Is there a Calculus book you can recommend? I don't want to go through a book that doesn't arm me with the proper tools that my brain needs to build chunks.

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for a function that looks like $f(t)=A\sin \bigl(B(t+C)\bigr)+D$. Now use the given information to find $A,B,C,D$. 
At $t=0$ we have that $f(0)=A\sin(BC)+D=-4$; because sine has minimum when angle is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, we can conclude that $BC=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $-A+D=-4$; 
At $t=6$ we have that $f(6)=A\sin\bigl(B(6+C)\bigr)+D=4$; because sine has maximum when angle is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, we can conclude that $B(6+C)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $A+D=4$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the question, the amplitude is $4$ and the period is $12$. So the $\sin$ function is compressed by a factor of $\frac{2 \pi}{12} = \frac{\pi}{6}$ in the $x$-axis.

Your value for the phase shift is incorrect. The maximum and the nearest zero are always separated by $\frac{1}{4}$ of a period: can you see why?

Applying the correct value of the phase shift gives you:

> $$4 \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{6}(x-3) \right)$$